# How make Json Jquery load when the page loads the info instead of using the click as per the example

Tags: jquery, html, json

I received this example from the usgs and I would like to use this code to automatically load the information when the page loads.  It is currently on click.
Details.

So what I would like to happen is to call this page as it loads it will pull in all of the information for the default value or site information which is value="04250200".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <title>USGS Water Services AJAX Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>USGS Water Services AJAX Example</h1>
    <p>This example shows how the USGS Instantaneous Values web service can be invoked using Asynchronous Javascript and XML (AJAX) technology. The jQuery framework is used.</p>
    <form id="form1" method="post" action="">
        <table width="100%" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td><label for="site"><strong>USGS Site No.</strong></label>              <input name="site" type="text" id="site" value="04250200" size="8" maxlength="15" /> 
              <a href="http://wdr.water.usgs.gov/nwisgmap/index.html">Find sites </a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><label for="sitedesc"><strong>Site Description</strong></label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><textarea name="sitedesc" cols="25" rows="2" readonly="readonly" id="sitedesc"></textarea></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><label for="discharge"><strong>Latest Streamflow ft.<sup>3</sup>/sec</strong></label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input id="discharge" size="7" readonly="readonly" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><label for="date"><strong>Date</strong></label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input id="date" size="10" readonly="readonly" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><label for="time"><strong>Time</strong></label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input id="time" size="5" readonly="readonly" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><label for="tz"><strong>Time Zone</strong></label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input id="tz" size="6" readonly="readonly" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      <p>
            <input type="button" name="query" id="query" value="Get Latest Streamflow" />
            <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
      </p>
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    // Proof of concept for AJAX usage with instantaneous values service
    $('#query').click(function() {
        site = $('#site').attr("value");
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=json&sites=" + site + "&parameterCd=00060",
          dataType: 'json',
          data: '',
          success: function(json){
               $('#sitedesc').text(json.value.timeSeries[0].sourceInfo.siteName);
               $('#discharge').val(json.value.timeSeries[0].values[0].value[0].value);
               datetime = json.value.timeSeries[0].values[0].value[0].dateTime;
               // Get date
               myDate = datetime.substr(5,2) + '/' + datetime.substr(8,2) + '/' + datetime.substr(0,4);
               $('#date').val(myDate);
               // Get time
               myTime = datetime.substr(11,5);
               $('#time').val(myTime);
               // Get timezone
               myTZ = datetime.substr(23);
               $('#tz').val(myTZ);
             },
          error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               $('#sitedesc').text('Error. Site Number was probably invalid or not a real-time site.');
               $('#discharge').val('');
               $('#date').val('');
               $('#time').val('');
               $('#tz').val('');
          }
        });
    });
//]]>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try using the $( document ).ready() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    site = $('#site').attr("value");
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=json&sites=" + site + "&parameterCd=00060",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: '',
      success: function(json){
           $('#sitedesc').text(json.value.timeSeries[0].sourceInfo.siteName);
           $('#discharge').val(json.value.timeSeries[0].values[0].value[0].value);
           datetime = json.value.timeSeries[0].values[0].value[0].dateTime;
           // Get date
           myDate = datetime.substr(5,2) + '/' + datetime.substr(8,2) + '/' + datetime.substr(0,4);
           $('#date').val(myDate);
           // Get time
           myTime = datetime.substr(11,5);
           $('#time').val(myTime);
           // Get timezone
           myTZ = datetime.substr(23);
           $('#tz').val(myTZ);
         },
      error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           $('#sitedesc').text('Error. Site Number was probably invalid or not a real-time site.');
           $('#discharge').val('');
           $('#date').val('');
           $('#time').val('');
           $('#tz').val('');
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Maximo that works beautifully also.   Sorry new to stack so I don't know how to vote and I can't seem to click on both answers to say they have answered.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$('#query').click(function() {
```

to

```
$(function() {
```

Comment: Thanks Chris that worked beautifully.  Thanks for replying I wish I could vote and also do the check mark for you also.  Thank you

Comment: @VarickDesign you can upvote any/all answers, but only accept one. Just pick the answer that was the most helpful to you

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I still can't vote cause I just joined but your reply got me going.  Thanks again :)

Comment: Ah, you're right, I was looking at @Maximo's 21 rep thinking that was you. You'll be able to up vote at 15

Comment: @VarickDesign I upvoted your question to get you on your way :)